# AngularDart ngFor with input change

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Tasks structure like: `<Map<String,String>>[{'_tasknumber':'123'}]`

[Repository](https://github.com/Rasarts/angulardart-ngfor-with-input-change)

```
@Component(
    template: '''
    <div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
                <label for="fileInput">
                    <material-button>
                        Add image 
                    </material-button>
                </label>

          id: {{task['_tasknumber']}}

          <input type="file"
                id="fileInput"
                multiple
                #fileInput
                (change)="uploadFilesForTask(fileInput.files, task['_tasknumber'])"/>
    </div>
    ''')
```

In function uploadFilesForTask I just print taskId value:

```
Future<Null> uploadFilesForTask(
      List<File> files, String taskId) async {
    print(taskId);
}
```

When I press "Add image" button I every time get id of first task in list of  tasks.

When I press input button "Choose files" I get right id what I need.

How I can get right id of task by "Add image" button?

**pubspec.yaml**:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.2'

dependencies:
  angular: '^4.0.0'
  angular_forms: '^1.0.0'
  angular_router: '^1.0.2'
  angular_components: '^0.8.0'
```

Comment: What is `'_tasknumber'`?

Comment: Just string in tasks structure like: <Map<String,String>>[{'_tasknumber':'123'}]

Comment: I'm sure there is something wrong with your map. Perhaps accidentally assigned the same instance to every `task` in `tasks` or similar.

Comment: But I think it's not ok: https://imgur.com/a/M0VdU

Comment: Please add the code to your question how you `id: ...` to the label like shown in your screenshot.

Comment: It's not a part of the label. I add this for example just in template.

Comment: Please add it to the question as well. You should be aware that a question provides much less insight than a computer where you can actively debug. We can only guess about what is happening on your site about things that are not explicitly stated in your question.

Comment: I made repository with example: https://github.com/Rasarts/angulardart-ngfor-with-input-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use not unique *label* **for** attribute.

Not right:

```
<label for="fileInput">
                    <material-button>
                        Add image 
                    </material-button>
                </label>

          <input type="file"
                id="fileInput"
                multiple
                #fileInput
                (change)="uploadFilesForTask(fileInput.files, task['_tasknumber'])"/>
```

Right:

```
<label [attr.for]="task['_tasknumber']">
                    <material-button>
                        Add image 
                    </material-button>
                </label>

          <input type="file"
                [attr.id]="task['_tasknumber']"
                multiple
                #fileInput
                (change)="uploadFilesForTask(fileInput.files, task['_tasknumber'])"/>
```